# Database migrations support in play framework?

Tags: nosql, playframework

Ruby on Rails has ActiveRecord and migrations for database schema and data migrations.
Does play framework has support like this (both schema and data migrations)?
What if NoSQL database is used in play framework, does it still support database migrations?

Comment: For NoSQL, there is no schema so migration is no exactly the same process as SQL. It deals with data migration and not model migration.

Answer (score 3):

Since Play 1.2 there exists an build-in solution called [evolution](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.1/evolutions). Another approach is to use the liquibase-plugin, which is database independent.

Answer (score 0):

For Play & SQL there seem's to be module [migrate](http://www.playframework.org/modules/migrate) in addition to evolutions.

Differences:

- With migrate you can run up scripts separately from application starting
- Down migrations not implemented yet